# Enctype="multipart/form-data" is notworking in linux environment?

Tags: linux, playframework-2.0, multipartform-data, enctype

I have a web application and now we want to move that from windows to linux environment.Here issue is,If i use enctype="multipart/form-data" in form tag then post request fails.For testing purpose i have removed enctype="multipart/form-data" from form tag and run in linux environment.Now post request success,But as per my knowledge for uploading files we should use enctype="multipart/form-data" in form tag.How to solve this issue?Please help me,For all help thanks in advance.

```
<form  action="@routes.HoForms.uploadHoFormsByHeadOffice()" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" id="shiftSummaryForm">//post request fails in linux

<form  action="@routes.HoForms.uploadHoFormsByHeadOffice()"  method="POST" id="shiftSummaryForm">//post request success in linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution for my problem above.What the problem is in my tomcat folder there is no folder created at the time of installation or may be i was deleted that folder unfortunately.Now i have temp folder in my tomcat folder and everything works fine.Thank you all for your valuable suggestions.